# How to modify the parsing of my Python script

Tags: python

#### Edit: sample code https://replit.com/@JustinEzequiel/CoralFrighteningSign thanks to JustinEzequiel

This is my current code.

```
import yaml
filepath = input("input path to file: ")
data = {}  # start a new dictionary


with open(filepath) as fh:
    for index, line in enumerate(fh):  # iterate by-line
        if index % 4 == 1:
            host = line  # do any needed validation here
            data[host] = {}  # start another dict to write to
        elif index % 4 == 2:
            host = line.strip()
            data[host]["hostname"] = line.strip()  # host is still the block header!

with open("output.txt", "w") as fh:
    yaml.dump(data, fh)
```

It outputs something like this

```
    '
? 'D32489DJ

  '
: hostname: 'D32489DJ

    '
```

(if D32489DJ) was the host name.

I want to make it output something like

```
D32489DJ: 
  hostname: D32489DJ
  nodename: D32489DJ
  username: rundeck
  tags: 'rundeck'
```

How can I modify my code to make this possible?

#### Snippet of file path

all you have to do is drag the file into your terminal after you run the program, make a new txt file named whatever you want.

put this exactly as it is line by line

```
hLKJH3019
BNKASDL32
dDASJKLH3
CNBAhsa32
ddkLJASCNjdaskA
```

that's what it looks like in my file, just random host names that don't make any sense separated line by line.

Comment: Post a snippet of the contents of `filepath` so that we can run your code.

Comment: Try `host = line.strip()` and `data[host]["hostname"] = line.strip()`. You forgot about the `\n` at the end of each line.

Comment: Also, see [sample code](https://replit.com/@JustinEzequiel/CoralFrighteningSign) showing code that does not require one to have to create files on our file systems.

Comment: I added what you suggested, still same issue (updated my code in the post) also the sample code doesn't seem to loop, it only print's one hostname.

Comment: "the sample code doesn't seem to loop" -- because you only gave five lines of text. What do you think `if index % 4 == 1:` does?

Comment: Besides, you forgot to change `host = line` to `host = line.strip()`. I told you to make two changes yet you forgot to do the first one.

Comment: I see now where you placed the `host = line.strip()` line. Why insert that there?

Comment: I see now that I'll have to post an answer and hope that you'll figure out how to change your code accordingly. If you cannot figure that out then perhaps you need to go through a tutorial or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to string the `\n` (linebreaks) at the end of each line.

```py
from io import StringIO
import yaml
import sys

data = '''\
hLKJH3019
aaa
dDASJKLH3
CNBAhsa32
ddkLJASCNjdaskA
bbb
BNKASDL32
dDASJKLH3
CNBAhsa32
ccc
hLKJH3019
BNKASDL32
dDASJKLH3
ddd
ddkLJASCNjdaskA
'''

fh = StringIO(data)
data = {}  # start a new dictionary

for index, line in enumerate(fh):  # iterate by-line
    if index % 4 == 1:
        host = line.strip()  # do any needed validation here
        data[host] = {}  # start another dict to write to
    elif index % 4 == 2:
        data[host]["hostname"] = line.strip()  # host is still the block header!

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

Comment: I'm kinda confused on what to do with this, it just prints out the line after opposed to inserting it into the text, maybe I'm just being dumb (probably) but how do I do this? Edit: Ok, I figured out what to do but how do I make it print out more than four lines at a time.

Comment: I suggest you go through a tutorial or two. I do NOT recommend those on youtube.

Comment: Tutorial on what? I have used python for about two years now just haven't done stuff like this. I'm assuming it's something with the modulo? I changed the number 4 to 5, and 10, and it didn't output more results.